# Why does Math.cos(90 * Math.PI/180) yield 6.123031769111... and not zero?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

I convert degrees to radians (degrees * Math.PI/180) but why does the following:

```
Math.cos(90 * Math.PI/180)
```

yield 6.123031769111... and not zero?

I'm trying to perform 2D rotations uses matrixes and the results are completely out of whack.

Comment: You should show more code so we can see some context.

Comment: @Gabe- Actually, the above code is sufficient.  Try typing it into a JS console and you will indeed get the result shown above.

Answer (score 41):

The output of

```
Math.cos(90 * Math.PI/180)
```

is

```
6.123031769111886e-17
```

Notice the `e-17` at the end, which means that this number is 6.123 x 10<sup>-17</sup>.  This is a number so vanishingly close to 0 that it's effectively 0.  The reason that it's not identically 0 is due to rounding errors in the IEEE-754 double format which prevents you from getting an exact representation of π / 2 and causes minute rounding errors in the calculation of the cosine.

By the way - I was pretty surprised as well when the result came back starting with a 6!  It's only after I looked at the very end that things started to make sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: and the fact that `Math.PI != π`.

Comment: +1. Maybe add something like `Math.cos(90 * Math.PI/180).toFixed(15)` as a simple solution?

Comment: ``( Math.cos( 90 * Math.PI / 180 ) | 0 ) === 0``

Answer (score 3):

```
6.123233995736766e-17
```

is scientific notation for a very small number, close to zero. It is not exactly zero because of rounding errors and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

6.123233995736766e-17 is very very close to zero. Just round the number.